# can't translate my program via debian package but with autotools can

Tags: linux, translation, gettext, autotools, deb

i use autotools as build system also i use gettext in my code for Translations.
I have few .po files (*de.po, es.po and th.po* ) and with autotools no problem to get them working. After:

```
./configure,
make 
sudo make install
```

the program and the Translations .mo files get installed.
To testing that i open a terminal and change the locale e.g :

```
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 
$ ./myprogram
```

**and the translations works!**.

I  do with the same source code a debian deb package.
During the deb installation in a .*posinst script* i deploy the translations mo files to the locale destination (***docklight*** is the program name):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# check for locale dir (LIVE SYSTEMS don't have it)
if [  -d "/usr/local/share/locale" ]; then
    podir="/usr/lib/docklight/docklight.data/po"
    if [ -d ${podir} ]; then
        cd ${podir}
        PO_LINGUAS=$( if test -r LINGUAS; then grep -v "^\#" LINGUAS; fi)
        linguas=$PO_LINGUAS
        for lang in $linguas; do

            dir=/usr/local/share/locale/$lang/LC_MESSAGES;

            # check for locale dir (LIVE SYSTEMS don't have it)
            if [ ! -d $dir ]; then
               continue;
            fi

            # check for po file
            if [ ! -f "$lang.po" ]; then
               continue;
            fi

            file=`echo $lang | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
            && rm -f $file && /usr/local/bin/msgfmt -o $file "$lang.po"

            /bin/bash install-sh -d $dir; \
            if test -r $lang.gmo; then \
                /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $lang.gmo $dir/docklight.mo; \
                echo "installing $lang.gmo as $dir/docklight.mo"; \
                else \
                /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$lang.gmo $dir/docklight.mo; \
                echo "installing ./$lang.gmo as" \
                "$dir/docklight.mo"; \
            fi

        done    
    fi
fi
```

the generated Translations .mo files are correct and get installed on the locale folder for the language:

```
dir=/usr/local/share/locale/$lang/LC_MESSAGES;
```

exact the same like the build process with autotools.
After testing the languages:

```
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 
$ ./myprogram
```

**my program does not have any translation.**
I don't know where the problem is. The deb installation works correct!

is something more that i need to care for the creation of a debian deb package?

As far as I understood, when you get myprogramm.mo files in place you should get the program translated.

Any ideas about that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if find the solution:
I just need to set the PROGRAMNAME_LOCALEDIR path where the mo file are.
The gettext initialization can find the mo files and then everything gets translate. **Works**!

```
  bindtextdomain(GETTEXT_PACKAGE, PROGRAMNAME_LOCALEDIR);
  %s\n",domain,GETTEXT_PACKAGE,PROGRAMNAME_LOCALEDIR);
  bind_textdomain_codeset - set encoding of message trans‐lations
  btdcodeset = bind_textdomain_codeset(GETTEXT_PACKAGE, "UTF-8");
```

Thank you all.